# OS X 10.11—workaround for downloading El Capitan

Tags: mac-appstore, macos

I have a Mac Pro 1.1 with OS X 10.10 Yosemite and Piker Alpha bootloader. I’m trying to download OS X 10.11 El Capitan from the Mac App Store and get the following error message:

> Your Purchase Could Not Be Completed.
>
> This version of OS X 10.11 can't be installed on this computer.

Is there a workaround for this problem? I have no other compatible Mac at home.

I only want to download the dmg file to edit it manually.

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208660/alternative-method-to-acquire-el-capitan-upgrade for a near duplicate question.

Comment: the answer is: change SystemVersion.plist

Comment: Perhaps you could answer your own question.  What key(s) did you change to what value in /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist ?

Comment: It wasn't the complete answer...
if you start the mac app store and edit in the SystemVersion.plist, 
you can josh the mac app store:

<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :ProductUserVisibleVersion '10.09'" /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :ProductVersion '10.09'" /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist

For Example.
Correct it after the josh, otherwise your system would be corrupted.

Comment: so i still search for a posibility...
i mean chameleon can do this, but is there a buildin way?