# Alternative Method to Acquire El Capitan Upgrade

Tags: upgrade, macos

Is there a way to acquire a copy of the El Capitan upgrade without downloading it first via the App Store, for example via a USB Drive? I know you can make a USB Drive after downloading El Capitan, but I am trying to skip the download itself.

Comment: Are you near an Apple Store or Apple retailer? Maybe they could put a copy of the installer on a USB stick or drive for you.

Answer (score 4):

Don't is my recommendation. This is how malware gets introduced into Apple software - like the Xcode ghost where developers were not downloading from Apple and not checking the validity of the software they installed.

If you call AppleCare, they might sell you physical media or even comp the shipping charge if they feel yours is a legitimate need to avoid the download. You could also find someone you trusted to [have them make you an installer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/16560/5472) and ship it to you.

I have known people that went to an Apple store and asked if they could sign in to the App Store on a Mac there and download the installer to a USB drive. Since the store probably runs a caching server, even downloading 10 GB of data would proceed in a matter of minutes.

- [What is the best way to generate a Yosemite or Mavericks Install USB flash drive?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106088/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-yosemite-or-mavericks-install-usb-flash-drive)

Comment: Called AppleCare, and the rep suggested I take my machine to a store to have it upgraded. I have a 27" iMac so I don't feel like doing that.

Comment: @RHPT Hmm - so they figured the Apple Store network would be faster. I've added a link to how you could go to any network that's faster than yours (even the Apple Store) with just your AppleID and a USB drive to download the installer and make a bootable USB drive.

Answer (score -2):

https://7labs.heypub.com/tips-tricks/el-capitan-direct-download.html

go to this site and you will get instructions on how you can download it.